# How to Append Sequence of Numbers to List?

Tags: list-manipulation

This would seem like a rather common thing to do: I've been trying since yesterday to `Append` a increasing sequence of numbers to my list of a pair of numbers. Researching possible solutions, I've explored using `MapThread`, `@@@` and `Module` in various combinations to no effect. Returning to my original approach, it's not behaving as expected. (I understand the result, just not how to get the result I want.)

```
data = Partition[RandomSample[Range[100]],2,1];
seq = Range[Length[data]];
Append[#,seq] &/@ data
```

Expected result:

`{{23,45,1},{45,67,2},{89,4,3},...}`

Update1:

Uh.. In regards to the suggestion this is a duplicate: As a beginner, I can't even comprehend the code in the linked question. (Like what is the `Min` in the question?) Ultimately, I'd still have followup questions. I'm just running in the possible suggested solutions from this thread now. Thanks to all who offered answers.

Comment: `Join[data, List/@seq, 2]` or `MapThread[Append, {data, seq}]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[Join, data]
MapIndexed[Join]@data (*in versions 10+ *)
```

> {{81, 15, 1}, {15, 1, 2}, {1, 68, 3}, {68, 4, 4}, ... , {63, 58, 98}, {58, 54, 99}}

Comment: Amazing. There's a function built right in that does this. I could have been wondering around in the woods for years before discovering this. TY.

Comment: @BBirdsell, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are lots of ways. Here's one:

```
data = Partition[RandomSample[Range[100]],2,1];
Flatten[{data[[#]], #}] & /@ Range[Length[data]]
{{60, 77, 1}, {77, 62, 2}, {62, 37, 3}, {37, 22, 4}, ....
```

Comment: I never would have thought of this but did test it out. I just want to wake up one day knowing this stuff. Thanks so much for everyone's time.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility

```
n=2;
data=Partition[RandomSample[Range[10]],n,1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
seq=Range[Length[data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now `Riffle` can be used. But need a small adjustment

```
 Partition[Flatten[Riffle[data,seq]],n+1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Long winded but fairly straightforward:

```
data = RandomChoice[Range[9],{10,2}]
end = Length[data]
Table[{First[data[[n]]],Last[data[[n]]],n},{n,1,end}]
```