# Tagging a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, insert

This is probably a stupid question, but I am having problems trying to  tag a list with identifying integers.

For example I have tried to tag `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` into `{{a,b,1},{c,d,2},{e,f,3}}`, via:

```
For[i==1,i<4,i++,Insert[{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}[[i]],i,3]]
```

and

```
For[i==1,i<4,i++,Append[{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}[[i]],i]]
```

and

```
Do[Insert[{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}[[i]],i,3],{i,3}].
```

However nothing so far has been successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Also note that I would like to be able to remove these tags later.

Comment: As @tomd points out, possible duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157359/how-to-append-sequence-of-numbers-to-list/157366#157366) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67423/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-current-matrix-list) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns).

Answer (score 7):

How about using [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) :

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
tagged = MapIndexed[Append[#1, First@#2] &, list]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}}
> ```

To remove the tags later, you can do

```
Most /@ tagged
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
> ```

**Edit**:  Thanks to [tomd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/106/tomd) for pointing out [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s [syntactic wonder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157366/106) :

```
MapIndexed[ Join, list ]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}}
> ```

As kglr points out, the operator form can also be convenient :

```
MapIndexed[Join] @ list
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}}
> ```

Comment: (+1) Or, as [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) has shown us [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157366/106), `MapIndexed[Join, list]`.  Just for fun: `MapIndexed[Join[#1, #2 - 1] &, list]`

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities (there are many more):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; 

Flatten /@ Transpose[{list, Range[Length[list]]}]
i = 1; Join[#, {i++}] & /@ list
```

both of which give

```
(* {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}} *)
```

If you really want to use `Do` and `Insert`, you need to remember that `Do` does not produce an output by default, and `Insert` doesn't modify the list in its first argument (it just creates a new list). But you could use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html), for example:

```
Reap[Do[Sow@Insert[list[[i]], i, -1], {i, Length[list]}]][[-1, 1]]

(* {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}} *)
```

To modify `list` directly in a `Do` loop, you could use `AppendTo`:

```
Do[AppendTo[list[[i]], i], {i, Length[list]}]
list

(* {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 3}} *)
```

You might also consider tagging by [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html)

```
listindex = PositionIndex[list]

(* <|{a, b} -> {1}, {c, d} -> {2}, {e, f} -> {3}|> *)
```

which you can use to get the index of any element of `list` by, for example

```
listindex[{c, d}]

(* {2} *)
```